# Calculus 2 - Comparison Theorem

Tags: calculus

Determine whether the improper integral is divergent.

$\int_1^\infty \frac{(x+\sqrt{x}+sin(x)+1)}{x^3+(e^(x^3))+\sqrt{x+7}}dx $

Comparison theorem:
1. $ 0<=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x}+sin(x)+1)}{x^3+(e^(x^3))+\sqrt{x+7}} <= \frac{4x}{x^3} $

How do you know what equation to use? Why are you allowed to do $\frac{x+x+x+x}{x^3}$
Why can't you use $4x^3$? or $\frac{4x}{x^2} $

Comment: I can't clearly see how the right side of your inequality is actually bigger than the left one...though it actually is.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be careful with these estimations, as sometimes it is easy to miscalculate. Now, assuming $\;x\ge1\;$ :

$$\frac{x+\sqrt x+\sin x+1}{x^3+e^{x^3}+\sqrt{x+7}}\le\frac{x+x+1+1}{x^3}\le\frac{x+x+x+x}{x^3}=\frac{4x}{x^3}=\frac4{x^2}$$

and thus the integral is convergent...

Observe that at each step one can see clearly, hopefully, why the inequality is true.

Comment: Myself, I would have included absolute values at the beginning

Comment: Are you just assuming since x is the largest number for the numerator you just replace all the numbers with x?

Comment: @zhw. Why? What for? the integration interval is $\;[1,\infty)\;$ so everything here is positive...in fact, even greater than one, as pointed out in the answer.

Comment: @MeroFuruya  Well, if you mean that no matter what $\;x\ge1\;$ we take, then it is always greater than *or equal* to $\;\sqrt x\;$ and $\;\sin x\,,\,\,1\;$, then yes: that's what I did.

Comment: $\sin x$ is not positive. I'm just saying I would present it that way to emphasize the more general fact that absolute convergence implies convergence.

Comment: @zhw. Who cares about a bounded function? It is true that $\;\sin x\le 1\;$ in any case, and this is what I used. Anyway, the stressing could be in place for what you say, indeed.